# DiracDelta attributes

Tags: functions, language-design, attributes

Is there any reason why `DiracDelta` isn't a `NumericFunction` but `DiracComb` is?

I just ate a bug because of that inconsistency

Comment: `UndirectedEdge` has the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, applying `FullDefinition` I see that `DiracDelta` lacks the `NumericFunction` attribute. And indeed, `NumericQ[DiracComb[1]]` yields `True` whereas `NumericQ[DiracDelta[0]]` doesn't.

Although I'm not sure why that difference exists, you may perhaps be able to get the desired result (you didn't say what your bug was) by setting `SetAttributes[DiracDelta, NumericFunction]`. At least it then allows you to work with the knowledge that `NumericQ[DiracDelta[0]]` is `True`.

Actually, maybe it would be more correct to *remove* the `NumericFunction` from both... depends on what you want, I guess.