# Is UndirectedEdge[a,b] the same edge as UndirectedEdge[b,a]?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is `UndirectedEdge[a,b]` the same edge as `UndirectedEdge[b,a]`?
Then please consider this.

```
g = CompleteGraph[4, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: tri1]

If we ask to delete `UndirectedEdge[1,4]` or `UndirectedEdge[4,1]` gives the same result:

```
EdgeDelete[g, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}]
EdgeDelete[g, {4 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}]
```

[image: tri2]
[image: tri3]

Yet if we ask whether these edges were in the original graph, we receive different answers.

```
MemberQ[EdgeList[g], 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4]
(* True *)

MemberQ[EdgeList[g], 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 1]
(* False *)
```

This strikes me as inconsistent.

---

**Postscript: Should `UndirectedEdge` be orderless?**

@R.M 's response makes a lot of sense:

`MemberQ[EdgeList[g], b \[UndirectedEdge] a]` answers True if and only if `b \[UndirectedEdge] a`, is literally in `EdgeList[g]`.  It will not respond True if that edge is listed in `EdgeList[g]` as `a \[UndirectedEdge] b`.  However, `EdgeQ[g, b \[UndirectedEdge] a]` will respond True whether  that edge is stored in `EdgeList[g]` either as `a \[UndirectedEdge] b` or `b \[UndirectedEdge] a`.

Even so, it seems to me that `UndirectedEdge` ought to be `Orderless`.
Wouldn't it be preferable to behave like `Plus`?

Compare `Plus` and `UndirectedEdge`:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
Plus[x, y]
Plus[y, x]
Attributes[Plus]
Plus[x, y] == Plus[y, x]
Plus[x, y] === Plus[y, x]
```

[image: plus]

```
ClearAll[x, y]
x \[UndirectedEdge] y
y \[UndirectedEdge] x
Attributes[UndirectedEdge]
UndirectedEdge[x, y] == UndirectedEdge[y, x]
UndirectedEdge[x, y] === UndirectedEdge[y, x]
```

[image: undirectedEdge]

Comment: Also: `MemberQ[{a+b,b+c}, b+a]` gives `True`.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, `b+a` is read as `Plus[a,b]`, apparently because or the `Orderless` attribute of `Plus`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not inconsistent at all. You're using `MemberQ`, which only looks at the structural form and `UndirectedEdge[1, 4]` and `UndirectedEdge[4, 1]` are **not** the same, even though you know they mean the same thing. To check if an edge is in a graph, use `EdgeQ`

```
EdgeQ[g, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4]
EdgeQ[g, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 1]
(* True, True *)
```

---

I think it's probably just an oversight on WRI's part to not include the `Orderless` attribute and such oversights are [not uncommon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2133/5). I can't think of a reason why it shouldn't be `Orderless`. One can always add this to the definition as follows:

```
Unprotect[UndirectedEdge];
SetAttributes[UndirectedEdge, Orderless];
Protect[UndirectedEdge];
```

Now using `MemberQ` as in the question will yield `True` in both cases. However, I would not recommend doing this, because I think it is worth it to understand the structural and semantic differences between the two and one should always use the one appropriate for the task (and in this case, also has a more meaningful name).

Comment: +1 for pointing out structural/semantic difference between `MemberQ` and `EdgeQ`.

Comment: Nice answer. I had forgotten about `EdgeQ` and only after reading your answer do I understand why `EdgeQ` was created.

Comment: As of 12.1, there is a good reason for not having the `Orderless` attribute: the optional third argument.